# Show that the representation $\mathbb Z\ni a\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1& a\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is not completely reducible

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\rho : \mathbb Z \to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ be the representation defined by $\rho(1) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. I'd like to show that $\rho$ is not completely reducible.

1. I have one preliminary question (which is probably a silly one) - for what vector space $V$ is $\mathrm{GL}(V) \cong \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$?

   Firstly, I noted that $\rho(1)$ has an eigenvector, so the representation is not irreducible. So if it were completely reducible, it would have to break up as a direct sum of two $1$-dimensional sub representations. But a 1-dimensional subrep is given by an eigenvector - but $\rho$ only has one eigenvalue, which has a $1$-dimensional eigenspace. So this can't happen.
2. Is this reasoning OK?

   Once I've shown that the representation isn't irreducible, the problem is equivalent to showing that $\rho(1)$ cannot be diagonalised (which I've done by showing that the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is $1$, not 2).

   Depending on the answer to question (1), I could have reduced (excuse the pun) the amount of work by considering Jordan Normal Form ($\rho(1)$ is in JNF but isn't diagonal, so isn't diagonalisable).

Comment: I think I *am* being silly with question i). $V = \mathbb C^2$ as a  $\mathbb C$-vector space, right?

Comment: So the Jordan Normal Form argument *does* apply

Comment: Indeed, the vector space is $\mathbb C^2$., and yes, the JNF argument does work, too.

Comment: @Matt : The only such $V$'s you will find are those who are isomorphic to $\mathbb C^2$. This is the classical example where we have a counter-example to justify representation theory working only with finite groups. When in infinite group, the whole idea of computing characters to work with the representation is pointless.

Comment: @Patrick: Well... *pointless* is a bit too strong :) For example, in the correct context, the finite dimensional representation theory of many infinite groups (like semisimple Lie groups, say) is completely controled by characters.

Comment: Ohh. But then you're dealing with infinite character tables or something? Or does Maschke's theorem hold for those groups and the number of conjugacy classes is finite?

Comment: For simplicity, suppose you have a compact Lie group $G$. Then it has maximal compact subgroups, which are tori, and if we fix one, call it T, every element in G is conjugate to an element of T, so characters are determined by their restriction to T. Since T is not too complicated, one can do wonders with that.

Comment: Firstly, I noted that $\rho(1)$ has an eigenvector, so the representation is not irreducible.... Is this any proposition... if yes then can you give me its reference..thnx in advance @Matt

Answer (score 4):

*This CW answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As you already noted yourself in the comments you can take $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ and then a Jordan normal form argument is perfectly fine.