# Completely Reducible, Irreducible, Decomposable, Indecomposable Representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$.
Let $\varphi:G\to GL(V)$ be a representation.

If $G$ is infinite or $\text{char }F$ divide $|G|$ or $\dim{V}=\infty$,
then an irreducible representation of $G$ is still indecomposable?

Could anyone help me complete the table by give an example in each case?
(Or point out the mistakes in the chart.)
I am not familiar with the representation of **infinite** groups.
The examples are given as easy as possible.
Please avoid using module (if possible).
Thanks.

The representation $\varphi:\Bbb{Z}\to GL_2(\Bbb{C})$, $\varphi(n)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is not completely reducible see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121365).

[image]

Comment: Irreducible always implies indecomposable (you should prove this).

Comment: Is the definition of irreducible and decomposable representation of a infinite group the same as of a finite group? (I am not sure.)

Comment: Yes, (ir)reducible and (in)decomposable have definitions which are not dependent on whether the group is finite or not.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks! If they are the same, then I have already proven it. (as I do in the finite group case.)

Comment: Is there is any difference between completely reducible and decomposable representation?  @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @YasirMahsud decomposable just means not indecomposable. Completely reducible means that it is a direct sum of simples.

Comment: @YasirMahsud 
Focus on the suffix of the term "decompos**able**" and the first word of the term "**completely** reducible.
Decomposable just means that it can be able to be decomposed.
Completely reducible means that it can not only be reduced but also this reduced process can do continuously until it is reduced completely.
The following answer give some examples can help you to clarify the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify a couple of things:

A representation $V$ is *irreducible* if $U\leq V$ is a subrepresentation if and only if $U=\{0\}$ or $U=V$. It is *indecomposable* if whenever $V = U_1\oplus U_2$ with $U_1,U_2$ subrepresentations, we have $U_1=\{0\}$ or $U_2= \{0\}$.

Thus an irreducible representation is indecomposable, but the converse is false. If $G = \mathbb Z$ then $\rho\colon \mathbb Z\to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ given by $\rho(n) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ exhibits $\mathbb C^2$ as an indecomposable representation of $\mathbb Z$ which is not irreducible, since $\mathbb C.e_1$ is the unique proper nontrivial subrepresentation.

A *decomposable* representation is one which is not indecomposable. The relationship between the notions of irreducibility and complete reducibility is quite different however -- a representation is *completely reducible* if it is a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations. In particular, an irreducible representation is completely reducible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples.
The page number refer to Dummit and Foote's **Abstract Algebra** 3/e.
The gray region means that no module can satisfy the condition.

[image]

Focus on
the suffix of the term "decompos**able**" and
the first word of the term "**completely** reducible".
Decomposable just means that it can be able to be decomposed.
Completely reducible means that it can not only be reduced but also this reduced process can be done continuously until it is reduced completely.
This note may help someone to clarify the difference between decomposable and completely reducible.

Note that indecomposable doesn't imply irreducible.
Note that decomposable doesn't imply completely reducible.

Comment: Your graphic is misleading, you should not intersect circles but include one circle in the other if there are no element outside the intersections. The white and grey convention is just misleading.

Comment: @Dac0 Thanks for you recommendation. I learned these material one year ago. So I need some time to review. Then modify the diagram and given concrete examples, not just a reference.

Comment: that would be great